# Shortest distance between a plane and the origin

Tags: vectors

If the coefficients of the cartesian equation of a plane form the vector perpendicular to the plane, then shouldn't the shortest distance between the plane and the origin just be the magnitude of the normal vector? Since it originates from the origin and is perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: No, because you can scale any normal vector by a scalar ($\neq 0$) and it remains a normal vector.

Comment: Ohh yeah, that makes sense now thanks